# MySQL order by lowest and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Table Data: `select firstName, package_id, website from user`

**Please note, there are more than 30k rows in table.**

[image]

I am trying to display lowest `package_id` in each `website` and here is query

```
select firstName, package_id, website from user group by website order by package_id
```

[image]

It should display lowest package_id from each website but its incorrect, like for value `kahuta` it should return `6` and for `Null => 10` and `example.com => 9`

Comment: "rwp" has two 5's, with different first names. How did you determine to return "William" over "Tony"?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use aggregation.  Use filtering:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.package_id = (select min(u2.package_id)
                      from user u2
                      where u2.website <=> u.website
                     );
```

If performance is an issue, you want an index on `user(website)`.  However, you should check if it is used for `<=>`.  If not, then try using `=` and then additional logic for the `NULL` values.

Comment: I have more than 30000 rows in table, this query will not work :)

Comment: @WasimA. . . . I see no problem with that number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select u.* from user u
where not exists (
  select 1 from user
  where website <=> u.website and package_id < u.package_id
)
```

or join the table to a subquery that returns the *min* `package_id` for each `website`:

```
select u.* 
from user u inner join (
  select website, min(package_id) minpackageid
  from user 
  group by website
) g on g.website <=> u.website and g.minpackageid = u.package_id
```